# How to get Croped image path in onActivityResult()

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "In result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        mOriginal = convertBitmap(picturePath);
        mSelected.setImageBitmap(mOriginal);
    } else if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Uri filePathFromActivity = (Uri) extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        filePathFromActivity = Uri.parse(getRealPathFromUri(filePathFromActivity));
        picturePath = filePathFromActivity.getPath();
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
        // picturePath=selectedImage.getPath();
        Log.d("Crop Path", picturePath);
        //display the returned cropped image
        mSelected.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        crop_flag = true;
    }
}
```

in this i can get path using cursor.getSring() if request code is for gallery(RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) ,But how to get path if request code is for crop(PIC_Crop).
I cant understand where the crop image save in System and how to getits full path in string.

Comment: Well, doesn't filePathFromActivity give you the path?? I am confused what you need. The request_code PIC_DROP is something you define. So, it's not a standard term that everyone should know what it means. It's not a framework terminology or anything.

Comment: No ,filePathFromActivity doesn't return anything.it throws bellow Exception.java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.starlet.piceffect/com.starlet.piceffect.MainView}: java.lang.NullPointerException.and ya its PIC_CROP not PIC_DROP. :)